# How to get InMemoryFileUpload video file's duration in django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, moviepy

I've searched about that in the SO, but there solutions with video file's path. I need to get file's duration by InMemoryFileUpload or BytesIO in django. How can do that?

```
from moviepy.editor import VideoFileClip

def video_skip_validator(data):
    video_file = data.get("video")
    video = VideoFileClip(video_file)
    print(video.duration)
```

It raises `'InMemoryUploadedFile' object has no attribute 'endswith'` error.

Comment: use TemporaryFileUploadHandler may fix the issue.